# Unwanted Apache redirect behavior

Tags: apache, redirect, joomla, ubuntu-12.04, http-redirect

My Apache installation on my Ubuntu 12.04 server redirects requests addressed to:

```
http://87.73.120.126
```

to

```
http://90.184.18.96/joomla/index.php/jomsocial
```

The address 87.73.120.126 is my servers current IP-address. The address 90.184.18.96 was the one it had half a year ago.

My question is: why does it do this? and how do I make it stop?

Half a year ago I wanted to make requests to `http://90.184.18.96` redirect to `http://90.184.18.96/joomla/index.php/jomsocial`
I did this by adding this line:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://90.184.18.96/joomla/index.php/jomsocial
```

to the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

A couple of days ago I tried to solve the current redirect problem by changing the line above to:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ http://127.0.0.1/joomla/index.php/jomsocial
```

and rebooting the server. This did not solve the problem!
Then I tried to do a global file search for the string `90.184.18.96` using this command:

```
sudo grep 90.184.18.96 / -irn --exclude-dir={bin,lib64,opt,sbin,tmp,boot,lost+found,proc,selinux,dev,media,root,srv,lib,mnt,run,sys,mail,log,doc,src,recovery-mode} --color
```

this search revealed a couple of outdated CRON-entries that I also fixed to use 127.0.0.1 instead. This didn't help either. So, where could the string '90.184.18.96' be residing? I guess it must be *somewhere* in order for anything to redirect to that address.

This server runs Joomla from the path `/var/www/joomla/`. As this path is not excluded by my grep-search any redirection emerging from Joomla should be revealed by the grep-search.

Answer (score 0):

Two considerations:

1. Redirecting to 127.0.0.1 will redirect to the user's machine, not your server.  If you're only spanning one server, you should not include your server's IP (it's not nice to access a site with a domain i.e. www.your-domain.com and be redirected to an ip address). So the rule should use variables for the host: %{HTTP_HOST} and %{REQUEST_URI} for host and path.
2. Besides httpd.conf you may also have redirect rules in your .htaccess which resides in the webserver root: and it's a hidden file so it could have been skipped by your grep, have a look into that as well. Beware the syntax of .htaccess and httpd.conf is slightly different.
3. You're achieving two things with that redirect: point to an installation which is off-root (/joomla) and setting a different homepage.  Setting the homepage in Joomla is as easy as marking its menu item with a star in the menu item editor, so you might not need the second part.